# Strange values in MS flags for debug print

Tags: c++, c, flags

I see in the Microsoft driver code example debug trace flags:

```
#define DEBUG_TRACE_ERROR                           0x00000001  // Errors - whenever we return a failure code
#define DEBUG_TRACE_LOAD_UNLOAD                     0x00000002  // Loading/unloading of the filter
#define DEBUG_TRACE_INSTANCES                       0x00000004  // Attach / detatch of instances

#define DEBUG_TRACE_METADATA_OPERATIONS             0x00000008  // Operation to access / modify in memory metadata

#define DEBUG_TRACE_ALL_IO                          0x00000010  // All IO operations tracked by this filter

#define DEBUG_TRACE_INFO                            0x00000020  // Misc. information

#define DEBUG_TRACE_ALL                             0xFFFFFFFF  // All flags
```

As I know flags should be 2 in the power (like 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32) to not intersect.
But why *DEBUG_TRACE_ALL_IO* is 10 and *DEBUG_TRACE_INFO*  is 20 and not 16 & 32?

Comment: Literals `0x`something in [tag:c] are HEX. Take a look [HERE](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_constants.htm)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because values in this code are hex. 0x10 = 16.

Answer (score 4):

```
Hex: 0x00000001  0x00000002 0x00000004 0x00000008 0x0000010 0x00000020  
Dec: 1           2          4          8          16        32
```